# How to kill a process on ubuntu that won't die?

Tags: ubuntu, kill, ps

I am trying to kill this process that seems to be stuck in a loop:

```
> ps auxww | grep -E '^USER|bash'
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ubuntu     61505 99.7  0.0   8596   304 ?        R    Sep27 812:45 bash redacted
```

Things that have no effect despite returning exit code 0:

- `kill 61505` and `sudo kill 61505`
- `kill -KILL 61505` and `sudo kill -KILL 61505`
- `kill -9 61505` and `sudo kill -9 61505`
- `kill -TERM 61505` and `sudo kill -TERM 61505`
- `cpulimit --pid=61505 -l 1 -k` and `sudo cpulimit --pid=61505 -l 1 -k`

By no effect, I mean:

- `STAT` says `R`
- `TIME` continues to increase
- `sudo cat /proc/61505/stack` continues to change

---

I've looked up what the `STAT` value of `R` means, and it is:

> R  running or runnable (on run queue)

---

Debugging output from comments:

```
>  sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] 0x0

>  sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] function_trace+0x98/0x98
[<0>] do_translation_fault+0x64/0x9c
[<0>] do_mem_abort+0x4c/0xbc
[<0>] el1_abort+0x74/0xf4
[<0>] el1_sync_handler+0xac/0xcc
[<0>] el1_sync+0x7c/0x100
[<0>] schedule_tail+0x130/0x200
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x4/0x3c

>  sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] function_trace+0x98/0x98
[<0>] enter_from_kernel_mode+0x28/0x60

>  sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] fault_info+0x60/0x600

>  sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] fault_info+0x60/0x600

# a while later

> sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] el1_irq+0xd8/0x180
[<0>] handle_mm_fault+0xc8/0x294
[<0>] do_page_fault+0x14c/0x4e0
[<0>] do_translation_fault+0x64/0x9c
[<0>] do_mem_abort+0x4c/0xbc
[<0>] el1_abort+0x74/0xf4
[<0>] el1_sync_handler+0xac/0xcc
[<0>] el1_sync+0x7c/0x100
[<0>] schedule_tail+0x130/0x200
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x4/0x3c

> sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] exit_to_kernel_mode+0x28/0x80

> sudo cat /proc/61505/stack
[<0>] __switch_to+0xb8/0xe4
[<0>] trace_hardirqs_off+0xd0/0x234
[<0>] el1_abort+0x84/0xf4
[<0>] el1_sync_handler+0xac/0xcc
[<0>] el1_sync+0x7c/0x100
[<0>] schedule_tail+0x130/0x200
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x4/0x3c
```

```
> sudo cat /proc/61505/wchan
0

> sudo cat /proc/61505/wchan
0

> sudo cat /proc/61505/wchan
0
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure it doesn't die at all, as opposed to getting automatically restarted (with new PID)? 2) What are the contents of `sudo cat /proc/61505/stack` and `sudo cat /proc/61505/wchan`?

Comment: Are you running under user account "ubuntu"?

Comment: @harrymc yeah, running as `ubuntu` user

Comment: @user1686 (1) after multiple kill attempts it is still the same pid and the runtime keeps increasing (2) added a few runs of each suggested command to the question

Comment: Have you started this `bash` command yourself? What was the last command you entered in it?

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately the logs have already expired for what was called and what the exact code was. It was a bash script that I was working on at the time. I believe there was a recursive self-call, which caused a segmentation fault. I had thought it had exited at the time, but seems it is still going.

Comment: A running process can not survive `kill -9`.  The only possibilities here are that either the kill didn't work (maybe it got an error?) or the process status changed (maybe to Z D or T) after you killed it.   Try running the kill as root.

Comment: @user10489 `sudo` has no effect on any of the kill variations, despite all returning exit code 0: `STAT` says `R`, `TIME` continues to increase, `%CPU` continues to fluctuate, and `sudo cat /proc/61505/stack` continues to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that is based on an answer to the post
[unkillable/unstoppable normal user process, how to forcedly control it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386776/unkillable-unstoppable-normal-user-process-how-to-forcedly-control-it)

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimited
sudo cgclassify -g cpu:cpulimited 61505
cd /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpulimited
echo 1000000 | sudo tee cpu.cfs_period_us
echo 1000 |sudo tee cpu.cfs_quota_us
```

This might not work if the process is not using any CPU.

Try `pgrep -P 61505` to find if `bash` cannot terminate because
of some child process.

Comment: Will try the limiter function later. `pgrep -P 61505` and  `sudo pgrep -P 61505` outputs nothing and returns with exit code `1`

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this answer was in front of you the entire time.

Reboot the computer.

Rebooting the computer would kill the process that won't die, and is the best solution for this as trying to "unclog" the process would likely make the kernel crash.

Comment: You can't always turn things off and on again. We don't know if there is anything running on this machine which would be impacted by restating the computer.